# Don't generate thumbs for CPT

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm looking for a way to to avoid the creation of image thumbs when uploading new images in a CPT.

So in my functions.php I had:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 56, 56, true ); // Normal post thumbnails
add_image_size( 'tinyfeatured', 50, 50, true ); // Tiny Featured thumbnail
add_image_size( 'blogonecol', 530, '', true ); // Blog One Column thumbnail
add_image_size( 'post', 530, '', true ); // Portfolio Large thumbnail
add_image_size( 'postnc', 700, '', false ); // Portfolio Large thumbnail
add_image_size( 'carousel', 560, 341, true ); // Portfolio Large thumbnail
add_image_size( 'magazine-full', '', 1131, true); // Portfolio Large thumbnail
}
```

and to avoid creating all this image sizes for a CPT that i'm using, i did this:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
if( !is_singular('issues') ) {
set_post_thumbnail_size( 56, 56, true ); // Normal post thumbnails
add_image_size( 'tinyfeatured', 50, 50, true ); // Tiny Featured thumbnail
add_image_size( 'blogonecol', 530, '', true ); // Blog One Column thumbnail
add_image_size( 'post', 530, '', true ); // Portfolio Large thumbnail
add_image_size( 'postnc', 700, '', false ); // Portfolio Large thumbnail
add_image_size( 'carousel', 560, 341, true ); // Portfolio Large thumbnail
}
add_image_size( 'magazine-full', '', 1131, true); // Portfolio Large thumbnail
}
```

but still, when i upload new images within the CPT "Issues", all the above image sizes are created.

Is there another way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `unset( $sizes['tinyfeatured']);` inside a conditional so when it is CPT "Issues" you unset the sizes but when its the opposite set the sizes. Like so:

```
if( is_singular('issues') ) {
  function sgr_filter_image_sizes( $sizes) {
    
    unset( $sizes['tinyfeatured']);
    unset( $sizes['blogonecol']);
    unset( $sizes['post']);
    unset( $sizes['postnc']);
    unset( $sizes['carousel']);

    return $sizes;
  }
    add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'sgr_filter_image_sizes');
}
```

More information and cited from [**Remove WordPress default media image sizes**](http://www.studiograsshopper.ch/code-snippets/remove-wordpress-defaultmedia-image-sizes/)

**EDITED**
Try this for size

```
function add_new_thumbnails() {
  if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
  add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

  set_post_thumbnail_size( 56, 56, true ); // Normal post thumbnails
  add_image_size( 'tinyfeatured', 50, 50, true ); // Tiny Featured thumbnail
  add_image_size( 'blogonecol', 530, '', true ); // Blog One Column thumbnail
  add_image_size( 'post', 530, '', true ); // Portfolio Large thumbnail
  add_image_size( 'postnc', 700, '', false ); // Portfolio Large thumbnail
  add_image_size( 'carousel', 560, 341, true ); // Portfolio Large thumbnail
  add_image_size( 'magazine-full', '', 1131, true); // Portfolio Large thumbnail
  }
 }
 add_action('after_setup_theme', 'add_new_thumbnails',10); //10 is default
```

use this along with the top code but add the filter priority of `12`

`add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'sgr_filter_image_sizes',12);`

**Try This Link** [**my snippet**](https://gist.github.com/davidchase/9944ab91a348c2fd32b5)

put that in your functions.php instead the code that was there and that you added

### New Method

So a new method to attempt is this one:

```
function add_new_thumbnails() {
 add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

 set_post_thumbnail_size( 56, 56, true ); // Normal post thumbnails
 add_image_size( 'tinyfeatured', 50, 50, true ); // Tiny Featured thumbnail
 add_image_size( 'blogonecol', 530, '', true ); // Blog One Column thumbnail
 add_image_size( 'post', 530, '', true ); // Portfolio Large thumbnail
 add_image_size( 'postnc', 700, '', false ); // Portfolio Large thumbnail
 add_image_size( 'carousel', 560, 341, true ); // Portfolio Large thumbnail
 add_image_size( 'magazine-full', '', 1131, true); // Portfolio Large thumbnail
}

add_action('init', 'add_new_thumbnails',10); //10 is default

if ( is_singular('issues') ) {
function remove_thumbnails() {
    add_image_size( 'tinyfeatured', 0, 0 ); // Tiny Featured thumbnail
    add_image_size( 'blogonecol', 0, 0); // Blog One Column thumbnail
    add_image_size( 'post', 0,0 ); // Portfolio Large thumbnail
    add_image_size( 'postnc',0,0 ); // Portfolio Large thumbnail
    add_image_size( 'carousel',0,0 ); // Portfolio Large thumbnail
    add_image_size( 'magazine-full',0,0); // Portfolio Large thumbnail
 }
add_action('init', 'remove_thumbnails',12); // 12 executes after 10

}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply David! I did this but still all image sizes are created :(

Comment: @user2093301 trying adding priority to `add_filter` if im not mistaken if your `add_image_size` are not in a callback they create new sizes ad default priority `10` which means we would ideally want to unset after `add_image_size` executes so try maybe `12` like so  `add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'sgr_filter_image_sizes',12);` remember all of this **only** affects newly created images not the ones you already uploaded

Comment: try wrapping the `add_image_size( 'tinyfeatured', 50, 50, true );` and others inside a function `add_new_thumbnails` and then use `add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_new_thumbnails', 10 );` and keep `add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'sgr_filter_image_sizes',12)`.

Comment: First of all let me say thank you for keeping up with my silly questions :) I've tried again like you advised, but still executes all image sizes. 

Updated code: http://pastebin.com/CT7yTwRr

Comment: let me give you the way to put it in the functions.php because you have one inside the other

Comment: tried that and still creates all image sizes. I even tried if(post_type_exists('issues'))  instead of if(is_singular('issues')) but still the same

Comment: try over writing the names and use 0 for height and width `add_image_size( 'tinyfeatured', 0, 0);` use this with priority 12

Comment: @user2093301 check new method

Comment: nothing changes :/ All your codes worked without errors, but the result still the same

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26398/discussion-between-david-chase-and-user2093301)